# Python Inverse of a Matrix

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix, linear-algebra, matrix-inverse

How do I get the inverse of a matrix in python? I've implemented it myself, but it's pure python, and I suspect there are faster modules out there to do it.

Comment: can you please show your algorithm?

Comment: there is answer here, if somebody wants a code snippet
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32114054/matrix-inversion-without-numpy

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You should have a look at [numpy](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html) if you do matrix manipulation. This is a module mainly written in C, which will be much faster than programming in pure python. Here is an example of how to invert a matrix, and do other matrix manipulation.

```
from numpy import matrix
from numpy import linalg
A = matrix( [[1,2,3],[11,12,13],[21,22,23]]) # Creates a matrix.
x = matrix( [[1],[2],[3]] )                  # Creates a matrix (like a column vector).
y = matrix( [[1,2,3]] )                      # Creates a matrix (like a row vector).
print A.T                                    # Transpose of A.
print A*x                                    # Matrix multiplication of A and x.
print A.I                                    # Inverse of A.
print linalg.solve(A, x)     # Solve the linear equation system.
```

You can also have a look at the [array](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/array.html) module, which is a much more efficient implementation of lists when you have to deal with only one data type.

Comment: numpy is also featured in the book "Beautiful Code". :-)

Comment: Note here also, that there's no inversion happening, and that the system is solved directly, as per John D. Cook's answer.

Comment: Consider using numpy [arrays instead of matrices](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html#array-or-matrix-which-should-i-use). Along with [`numpy.linalg`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.linalg.html), you can get pretty much everything you want, without using the unwieldy `numpy.matrix`.

Answer (score 57):

Make sure you really need to invert the matrix.  This is often unnecessary and can be numerically unstable.  When most people ask how to invert a matrix, they really want to know how to solve Ax = b where A is a matrix and x and b are vectors.  It's more efficient and more accurate to use code that solves the equation Ax = b for x directly than to calculate A inverse then multiply the inverse by B.  Even if you need to solve Ax = b for many b values, it's not a good idea to invert A.  If you have to solve the system for multiple b values, save the Cholesky factorization of A, but don't invert it.

See [Don't invert that matrix](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/).

Comment: What if my matrix members are exact rationals? It seems like that avoid the accuracy problem, although of course at the cost of making the performance problem a lot worse.

Answer (score 10):

It is a pity that the chosen matrix, repeated here again, is either singular or badly conditioned:

```py
A = matrix( [[1,2,3],[11,12,13],[21,22,23]])
```

By definition, the inverse of A when multiplied by the matrix A itself must give a unit matrix.  The A chosen in the much praised explanation does not do that. In fact just looking at the inverse gives a clue that the inversion did not work correctly.  Look at the magnitude of the individual terms - they are very, very big compared with the terms of the original A matrix...

It is remarkable that the humans when picking an example of a matrix so often manage to pick a singular matrix!

I did have a problem with the solution, so looked into it further.  On the ubuntu-kubuntu platform, the debian package numpy does not have the matrix and the linalg sub-packages, so in addition to import of numpy, scipy needs to be imported also.

If the diagonal terms of A are multiplied by a large enough factor, say 2, the matrix will most likely cease to be singular or near singular. So

```py
A = matrix( [[2,2,3],[11,24,13],[21,22,46]])
```

becomes neither singular nor nearly singular and the example gives meaningful results... When dealing with floating numbers one must be watchful for the effects of inavoidable round off errors.

Comment: one may also check A==A.I.I in order to verifiy the result

Comment: The problem is that humans pick matrices at "random" by entering simple arithmetic progressions in the rows, like 1, 2, 3 or 11, 12, 13. The problem is that if you have at least three rows like this they are always linearly dependent.

Answer (score 8):

For those like me, who were looking for a pure Python solution without `pandas` or `numpy` involved, check out the following GitHub project: https://github.com/ThomIves/MatrixInverse.

It generously provides a very good explanation of how the process looks like "behind the scenes". The author has nicely described the step-by-step approach and presented some practical examples, all easy to follow.

This is just a little code snippet from there to illustrate the approach very briefly (`AM` is the source matrix, `IM` is the identity matrix of the same size):

```
def invert_matrix(AM, IM):
    for fd in range(len(AM)):
        fdScaler = 1.0 / AM[fd][fd]
        for j in range(len(AM)):
            AM[fd][j] *= fdScaler
            IM[fd][j] *= fdScaler
        for i in list(range(len(AM)))[0:fd] + list(range(len(AM)))[fd+1:]:
            crScaler = AM[i][fd]
            for j in range(len(AM)):
                AM[i][j] = AM[i][j] - crScaler * AM[fd][j]
                IM[i][j] = IM[i][j] - crScaler * IM[fd][j]
    return IM
```

**But please do follow the entire thing, you'll learn a lot more than just copy-pasting this code!** There's a Jupyter notebook as well, btw.

Hope that helps someone, I personally found it extremely useful for my very particular task ([Absorbing Markov Chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain)) where I wasn't able to use any non-standard packages.

Answer (score 6):

You could calculate the determinant of the matrix which is recursive
and then form the adjoined matrix

[Here is a short tutorial](http://www.easycalculation.com/matrix/inverse-matrix-tutorial.php)

I think this only works for square matrices

Another way of computing these involves gram-schmidt orthogonalization and then transposing the matrix, the transpose of an orthogonalized matrix is its inverse!

Answer (score 5):

Numpy will be suitable for most people, but you can also do [matrices in Sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/matrices.html)

Try running these commands at http://live.sympy.org/

```
M = Matrix([[1, 3], [-2, 3]])
M
M**-1
```

For fun, try `M**(1/2)`

Comment: I found that `numpy.linalg` was giving inexact results for matrices containing large integers, whereas the results from `sympy` are exact. +1

Comment: With an approximate precision, Sympy is a good and live terminal. I checked with command `(M**-1)*M` and it gave unit matrix (not exactly but very close one)

Answer (score 1):

If you hate numpy, get out RPy and your local copy of R, and use it instead.

(I would also echo to make you you really need to invert the matrix.  In R, for example, linalg.solve and the solve() function don't actually do a full inversion, since it is unnecessary.)

Comment: Never used R, but why would an external program and its python binder be better than the most well known scientific package of python?