# Inverse of a matrix in PHP

Tags: php, matrix

I know how to calculate the inverse of a matrix but I am having difficulty applying it in `php`. I am new to `php` and got an assignment to create a `php` program that gives inverse of a matrix. 
Can anyone please help me to create this program? It would be very useful for my learning.
Below I have a 2x2 matrix in two arrays of which I took the Adjoint but now I'm having problems with further steps

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 5
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => -2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => -4
            [1] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP inverse of a matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811250/php-inverse-of-a-matrix)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of solutions.

- [Lapack](https://php.net/manual/en/lapack.pseudoinverse.php)

Example

```
<?php

$a = array(
    array( 8, 1, 6 ),
    array( 3, 5, 7 ),
    array( 4, 9, 2 ),
);

$result = Lapack::pseudoInverse($a);
?>
```

- [Math_matrix](https://pear.php.net/package/Math_Matrix/)
- [And a lot more in Composer](https://packagist.org/search/?q=matrix)