# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,) (30,)

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, valueerror

I am trying to merge arrays like this:

If:

```
a = [1.2, 1, 3, 4]
b = [0.0 , 0.0]
c = [0.0 , 0.0]
a = a + b + c
```

Then the result should be:

```
[0.0 , 0.0 , 1.2 , 1 ,3 ,4 , 0.0 ,0.0]
```

what I do is that extract histogram of array
  and merge it with normal array.

```
x1, bins, patch = plt.hist(array1, bins = round(max(array1) - min(array1)))
x1 = b + x1 + c

but the form of x1 is 
x1 = [  2.   0.   0.   1.   0.   2.   5.   0.   1.   1.   0.   1.   5.]
```

and maybe that cause the error like this

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,) (30,)

please help me.
  I don't know what to do

Comment: For your example do you mean a=b+a+c?

Answer (score 7):

You could use np.concatenate to to do this but you can also do this by converting your arrays to lists.

```
import numpy as np

a = list(np.array([1.2, 1, 3, 4]))
b = list(np.array([0.0 , 0.0]))
c = list(np.array([0.0 , 0.0]))
D= a + b + c
```

So in you code try:

```
x1 = list(b) + list(x1) + list(c)

#Put it back into a numpy array
x1 = np.array(x1)
```

Answer (score 1):

NumPy arrays behave differently with the `+` operator: with Python lists, adding lists together means concatenation (which is what you wanted).

However, in NumPy, adding arrays together means element-wise addition (and if the dimensions don't match, [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) first).

To get what you wanted, use `np.concatenate`, e.g.

```
import numpy as np
np.concatenate((b,x1,c))
```