# Invert matrix without Numpy in Python

Tags: python, numpy

i try this for matrix 2x2 and matrix 3x3 but i would like to use some loops like **for** or **while**.

```
from libmatrice import det2, det3, comatrice, transposee, inverse

reponse = input('Quelle est la dimension de la matrice à inverser (2 ou 3) ?\n')

determinant = 0

if reponse == '2':
    print('''Votre matrice est de dimension 2 (2 lignes et 2 colonnes)''')

    A11 = int(input('''Quel est votre premier chiffre ?\n'''))
    A12 = int(input('''Quel est votre deuxième chiffre ?\n'''))

    A21 = int(input('''Quel est votre troisième chiffre ?\n'''))
    A22 = int(input('''Quel est votre quatrième chiffre ?\n'''))

    determinant = det2(A11, A12, A21, A22)
    print('''Le déterminant de votre matrice 2x2 est : ''', determinant)

elif reponse == '3':
    print('''Votre matrice est de dimension 3 (3 lignes et 3 colonnes)''')

    A11 = int(input('''Quel est votre premier chiffre ?\n'''))
    A12 = int(input('''Quel est votre deuxième chiffre ?\n'''))
    A13 = int(input('''Quel est votre troisème chiffre ?\n'''))

    A21 = int(input('''Quel est votre quatrième chiffre ?\n'''))
    A22 = int(input('''Quel est votre cinquième chiffre ?\n'''))
    A23 = int(input('''Quel est votre sixième chiffre ?\n'''))

    A31 = int(input('''Quel est votre septième chiffre ?\n'''))
    A32 = int(input('''Quel est votre huitième chiffre ?\n'''))
    A33 = int(input('''Quel est votre neuvième chiffre ?\n'''))

    determinant = det3(A11, A12, A13, A21, A22, A23, A31, A32, A33)
```

print(determinant)

```
    comatrice = comatrice(A11, A12, A13, A21, A22, A23, A31, A32, A33) 

    print('''Votre comatrice est : ''', comatrice)

    detA11 = comatrice[0]
    detA12 = comatrice[1]
    detA13 = comatrice[2]
    detA21 = comatrice[3]
    detA22 = comatrice[4]
    detA23 = comatrice[5]
    detA31 = comatrice[6]
    detA32 = comatrice[7]
    detA33 = comatrice[8]

    transpose = transposee(detA11, detA21, detA31, detA12, detA22, detA32,detA13, detA23, detA33)

    TA11 = transpose[0]
    TA12 = transpose[1]
    TA13 = transpose[2]
    TA21 = transpose[3]
    TA22 = transpose[4]
    TA23 = transpose[5]
    TA31 = transpose[6]
    TA32 = transpose[7]
    TA33 = transpose[8]

    print('''La matrice inverse est : ''', inverse(determinant, TA11, TA21, TA31, TA12, TA22, TA32, TA13, TA23, TA33))

else:
    pass
```

And i also use a library but because i don't use loop, i don't need def reduit(matrix)

```
def det2(A11, A12, A21, A22):    
    diagonale_1 = A11*A22
    diagonale_2 = A12*A21
    resultat = diagonale_1 - diagonale_2
    return resultat

def det3(A11, A12, A13, A21, A22, A23, A31, A32, A33):
    #pour A11:
    diagonale_A11_1 = A22 * A33
    diagonale_A11_2 = A32 * A23
    resultat_A11 = diagonale_A11_1 - diagonale_A11_2
    #pour A12:
    diagonale_A12_1 = A21 * A33
    diagonale_A12_2 = A31 * A23
    resultat_A12 = diagonale_A12_1 - diagonale_A12_2
    #pour A13:
    diagonale_A13_1 = A21 * A32
    diagonale_A13_2 = A31 * A22
    resultat_A13 = diagonale_A13_1 - diagonale_A13_2
    #resultat final:
    resultat_final = A11 * resultat_A11 - A12  * resultat_A12 + A13 * resultat_A13
    return resultat_final


def reduit(matrice):
    pass

def comatrice(A11, A12, A13, A21, A22, A23, A31, A32, A33):
    detA11 = A22 * A33 - A32 * A23
    detA12 = -(A21 * A33 - A31 * A23)
    detA13 = A21 * A32 - A31 * A22
    detA21 = -(A12 * A33 - A32 * A13)
    detA22 = A11 * A33 - A31 * A13
    detA23 = -(A11 * A32 - A31 * A12)
    detA31 = A12 * A23 - A22 * A13
    detA32 = -(A11 * A23 - A21 * A13)
    detA33 = A11 * A22 - A21 * A12
    return detA11, detA12, detA13, detA21, detA22, detA23, detA31, detA32, detA33


def transposee(detA11, detA12, detA13, detA21, detA22, detA23, detA31, detA32, detA33):
    TA11 = detA11
    TA21 = detA12
    TA31 = detA13
    TA12 = detA21
    TA22 = detA22
    TA32 = detA23
    TA13 = detA31
    TA23 = detA32
    TA33 = detA33
    return TA11, TA21, TA31, TA12, TA22, TA32, TA13, TA23, TA33

def inverse(det, TA11, TA12, TA13, TA21, TA22, TA23, TA31, TA32, TA33):
    invTA11 = TA11 // det
    invTA21 = TA21 // det
    invTA31 = TA31 // det
    invTA12 = TA12 // det
    invTA22 = TA22 // det
    invTA32 = TA32 // det
    invTA13 = TA13 // det
    invTA23 = TA23 // det
    invTA33 = TA33 // det
    return invTA11, invTA12, invTA13, invTA21, invTA22, invTA23, invTA31, invTA32, invTA33
```

Do you have any idea in order to be more "clean" in my code in order to integrate some loop in my second code ?
The first block of code is called matrice.py witch is the interface where the program in python is asking if it's a 2x2 dimensions or 3x3 dimensions.

The libmatrice is import from libmatrice.py

Comment: Hello @Tluabiht, welcome to StackOverflow !
As your question appears to be more related to code reviewing than programming, I would ask your question to this site instead https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matrix inversion without Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32114054/matrix-inversion-without-numpy)

Answer (score 0):

you can work with `for` loops of you represent your matrices as lists (of lists):

```
A = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]

def det2(A):
    return A[0][0]*A[1][1] - A[0][1]*A[1][0]

def inv2(A):
    d = det2(A)
    return [[A[1][1]/d, -A[0][1]/d], [-A[1][0]/d, A[0][0]/d]]


print(det2(A))  # 2
print(inv2(A))  # [[-2.0, 1.0], [1.5, -0.5]]
```

an for 3 dimensions:

```
B = [[1, 21, 3], [3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 9]]

def det3(B):
    ret = 0
    for i in range(3):
        pos = 1
        neg = 1
        for j in range(3):
            pos *= B[j][(i+j) % 3]
            neg *= B[j][(i-j) % 3]
        ret += (pos - neg)

    return ret

def inv3(B):
    ret = [3*[None] for _i in range(3)]
    det = det3(B)
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            adj = [[n for ii, n in enumerate(row) if ii != i] 
                      for jj, row in enumerate(B) if jj != j]
            d = det2(adj)
            sgn = (-1)**(i+j)
            ret[i][j] = sgn * d / det
    return ret

print(det3(B))  # -42
print(inv3(B))
# [[-0.14285714285714285, 4.071428571428571, -2.2142857142857144], 
#  [0.047619047619047616, 0.14285714285714285, -0.09523809523809523], 
#  [0.047619047619047616, -2.357142857142857, 1.4047619047619047]]
```

note that the determinant for 2 dimensions is almost trivial; for the 3 dimensional one i used the [rule of sarrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus).

that might get you started on how to do the general case.